# Why $\vec F=m\vec a$ instead of $\vec F=m\vec v$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

$\vec F=m\vec a$ ,for moving object with 10 $km/s$ in a constant manner ,where acceleration is zero. ie No force on object ?

http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=622711

Comment: Elaborate your question. It makes no sense.

Comment: Your question is not clearly stated. What do you have a problem with?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87207/2451

Comment: -1 The question is not clear, and I am not willing to readd any linked website. It should be clear from itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Force is defined as something which can change the speed or direction of motion of an object. In other words, ***force causes acceleration***. If you invert this statement, you see that a body undergoing acceleration must mean there is some force acting on the body.

Therefore, acceleration and force *must* be related somehow. Therefore, $F = m v~$ is incorrect. The correct relation is $F = ma$

**Edit:**

From the referenced url:

> So if a car (say 2000kg) is travelling at a constant speed of say
>   70mph on the motorway, and I like to have a picnic in the center lane,
>   and that car hits me, the force it exerts should be zero because
>   F=2000 x 0 which is zero so no force exerted on me?

The car is traveling at a constant speed, so there is no ***net external*** force being exerted on the car. When the car hits you, obviously your velocity changes - you won't be enjoying the picnic anymore because you'd be in pieces, but if you were a rigid body, you would be intact but now you'd be moving at some velocity. That is to say, you underwent *acceleration*. The force on *you*, therefore, would be non-zero. By Newton's Third Law, the force on the car would also be non-zero and, without anything to counter this force (like the engine powering the wheels), the car would decelerate.